# Replace string characters with value of the same character in json

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

```
I have the following string `a+b*c` and  json : 

{    
    a: 'hello',
    b: 'hello2',
    c: 'hello3'.
}
```

I want to replace the letters in string so that the final string is 
`hello+hello2*hello3`.

Is there any simple way in Js or lodash to do this?

Comment: Are you really incapable of doing a web search for "replace string in javascript", or some equivalent?

Comment: @SamAxe Report it to the mods if you feel this is below your high standards.

Comment: You should not do this with a string replace. You should parse the json to a javascript object and process the properties of the object there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string into an array and then iterate the array to build the new string from the corresponding object properties

```js
var str = 'a+b*c',
  params = str.split(''),
  data = {
    a: 'hello',
    b: 'hello2',
    c: 'hello3'
  };

var res = params.reduce((a, c) => {
  return a += data[c] ? data[c] : c;
}, '')

console.log(res)
```